# Android. Button doesn't look pressed

Tags: android, button

i'm just getting started with Android development. I have a very simple button created like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/howItWorksButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:text="@string/how_it_works_button_title" />
```

In code i set background color for it:

```
howItWorksButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

this is onClickListener:

```
howItWorksButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, HowItWorksActivity.class);
            MainMenuActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

The problem is when i click it it doesn't look as if it's just been pressed, it just remains as it was, no changes. Its onClick method works ok, everything is fine with functionality, but i want it to look changed somehow, like all buttons do when they're pressed.

Comment: It will not **look like pressed** until and unless you add an **OnClickListener()** in your activity for this button.

Comment: @Numair i did it already

Comment: @TanjaV can you give an example please

Comment: @Numair You are wrong, you don't have to implement anything to see the pressed effect. Problem must be somewhere else. Andrey make sure you aren't doing something weird in the code

Comment: StateList: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: DO you have any custom theme applied?

Comment: @kaya all i do with the button in code is i set color for it

Comment: You shouldn't set color from code for your case

Comment: @AndreyChernukha all you need is a `<selector>` as answered by @Muraliganesan and you can set this .xml file as background to your button. It will give you the press like feel...

Comment: @kaya see my edited answer. i posted onClickListener

Comment: @kaya the problem lies in setting color. if i don't set color it looks pressed. So the question now is how to set color of the button in a different way

Comment: ok, posting an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Android doesn't show pressed state automatically unlike iOS, if you set its color manually. Here is the recommended way to do it.

Put a colors.xml folder in your values folder. Its contents should be like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="white">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="darkwhite">#ffeeeeee</color>
    <color name="transparent">#00ffffff</color>
    <color name="semitransparent">#88000000</color>
    <color name="orange">#ffff8800</color>
    <color name="light_orange">#ffe27d18</color>
    <color name="light_blue">#ff00a2e8</color>
    <color name="black">#ff000000</color>
    <color name="menuButtonColor">#ffea8e44</color>
</resources>
```

Put a selector file in your drawable for example

my_button_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/light_orange" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/orange"/>
</selector>
```

Use your selector like this

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/howItWorksButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:text="how_it_works_button_title"
    android:background="@drawable/my_button_selector" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

Use `Selector`.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/login_btn" android:state_pressed="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/login_btn_focus" android:state_pressed="true"/>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an image selector as background to tell android which image or color you want to be visible when the button is pressed, focussed, disabled, ...
Here you can find an example
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/

Comment: Setting only a color is not right. It will be used for each state (default, pressed, focussed, etc). So in reality nothing will change what you do with the button

Answer (score 0):

Write `android:state_pressed="  "` in both `pressed` and other `state`.

**When button is pressed**

```
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/green" />
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/btn_corner_rds" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

**when button is not pressed**

```
<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <stroke android:width="@dimen/stroke_width_btn"  />
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/btn_corner_rds" />
    </shape>
</item>
```